# split array based on value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this:

```
     array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "L2"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "L3"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Cat"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "L2"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Orange"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "L3"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Dog"
  }
}
```

I want make a conclusion:
a) what are content of L2?
b) what are content of L3?

So I make array $L2 and $L3.
But, I have no idea how to push some array in one array.
I already try this one:

```
for($j=0; $j<count($arrL); $j++){
    if($arrL[$j][0] == "L2"){
            $L2[] = $arrL[$j][1];
    }else if($arrL[$j][0] == "L3"){
            $L3[] = $arrL[$j][1];
    }
}
```

But, the result is:

```
array(0) {
}
```

you have any idea?

Comment: Your code runs just fine for me using an array constructed just like the one shown for $arrL.  Is it possible there's something else not working correctly?  are you correctly testing $L2 and $L3?  Is it possible $arrL is not constructed as shown?

Comment: Yeah don't see any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just fine. If I understand what do you want correctly then perhaps this might help you out. This is the code that I am using:

```
$arrL = array(
        0 => array(
                    0 => "L2", 1 => "Apple"
                ),
        1 => array(
                    0 => "L3", 1 => "Cat"
                ),
        2 => array(
                    0 => "L2", 1 => "Orange"
                ),
        3 => array(
                    0 => "L3", 1 => "Dog"
                )
    );

for($j=0; $j<count($arrL); $j++){
    if($arrL[$j][0] == "L2"){
        $L2[] = $arrL[$j][1];
    }else if($arrL[$j][0] == "L3"){
        $L3[] = $arrL[$j][1];
    }
}

echo 'My L2 Array: ';
print_r($L2);

echo 'My L3 Array: ';
print_r($L3);
```

And here is the output:

```
My L2 Array: Array ( [0] => Apple [1] => Orange ) My L3 Array: Array ( [0] => Cat [1] => Dog )
```